# Crunchbang Linux on Mac Mini 6,1

Tags: linux, macos, partitioning, grub, mac-mini

I have a Mac Mini (6,1) and I want to dual boot OSX with crunchbang (chose this distro because Wi-fi works out of the box).

First, I installed rEFIt and put crunchbang on a flashdrive.

Next, I partitioned my hard drive with OSX disk utility and created 250gb of free space

Then I rebooted, and started the crunchbang live disk and during the installation chose "Largest amount of continuous free space", which created a "space for BIOS" and ext4 partition (mounted at /)

After installing the system, I was asked where to put grub (do I put it on the space reserved for BIOS or do I put it on the ext4 partition??), and it gave me a weird list of disks/partitions, so I wasn't sure which one to put grub onto.

The options went (as best I can remember):

The first partition of the first disk. The second partition of the first disk. The first partition of the second disk. and the first partition of the third disk.

Out of fear I aborted the installation, as I've already had to replace my computer because of partitioning issues

If anyone has experience with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when installing #! on my MacBook. You probably want GRUB to be installed on the same partition where you installed #! (i.e. the same partition that you formatted as ext4 and mounted as root).

To figure out what partition this is, you can do the following during the install process:

- Press function-control-option-f2 (or whatever key combination is equivalent to control-alt-f2 for your keyboard). This will open a virtual terminal. When you are prompted, press enter to confirm that you want to open this terminal.
- Type `df` and hit Enter. You should see a line in the output that reads something like `Filesystem /dev/sda3 mounted on /target`. You want to remember the `/dev/sda3` bit (or whatever it happens to be; this is the partition where your new #! install is located.
- Press function-control-option-f5 (or, again, whatever key combo equals control-alt-f5) to get back to the install screen.
- Type in `/dev/sda3` (or whatever partition you just found) and continue.

Good luck. There is a lot that can go wrong besides this; it's not trivial to get OS X to boot nicely along side other OSs.